# How to check if given string can be formed from another string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I need to check if a given string can be formed from main string or not in Java .

**Example :**

**Input**

Main String - lhLoe

HELLO

eel

eL,$H.

**Ouput:**

HELLO : YES

eel : NO

eL,$H. : YES

I can try with permutation , but if the first string is long , it will take much time . Any other way to do this ?

Note: we can ignore special characters.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried that does not work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex and define your String as a character group.

Something like this:

```
    String search="lhLoe";
    String input="HELLO";
    input=input.replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z1-9]","");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^["+search+"]+$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    boolean b = m.matches();
```

Comment: This would return true for `hello` and `heel` -- which I suspect is not wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First, lowercase both strings, so that:

```
lowerCasedMainString = "hello"
lowerCasedTargetString = "el,$h"
```

Next remove special characters, since you say they can be ignored:

```
lowerCasedTargetStringStripped = "elh"
```

There are various ways you can tackle the rest of the problem, but I would do a loop like this (pseudocode):

```
while(length of target > 0) {
    char c = target.charAt(1);

    if(main contains c) {
       main = main with that instance of c removed
    } else {
       return false
    }

    target = target.substring(1);
}
return true;
```

Each individual step of this should be easily achievable. If you're tackling a problem like this, you've probably already seen the methods that will do it. Otherwise, there will be existing answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the occurrences of each character in the given main string in an array. (Let's call it array a.)

Repeat the same procedure for the given test strings. (Let's call it array b)

If the occurrence of each character in test string (array b) is less than equal to the occurrence of that corresponding character in the main string(array a), then, the test string can be formed using main string.

Runtime complexity will be linear.

Take care of case sensitivity and special symbols.